# AJAX Sql Update not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I stripped down my code to make this question a little simpler.

This is my PHP at the top of the file...

```
if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
  $field = $_POST['db_field'];
  $value = $_POST['db_value'];

$fields=array('points'=>($value));
  $db->update('teams',$field,$fields);
}
```

Then I have this script on the same page...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function performAjaxSubmission() {
       $.ajax({
         url: 'points3.php',
         method: 'POST',
         data: {
           action: 'save',
           field: $(this).attr("db_field"),
           val: $(this).attr("db_value")
         },
         success: function() {
           alert("success!");
         }
       });
       return false; // <--- important, prevents the link's href (hash in this example) from executing.
     }
     jQuery(document).ready(function() {
       $(".linkToClick").click(performAjaxSubmission);
     });
   </script>
```

Then I have 2 super simple buttons for testing purposes...
  Click here-1
  Click here-2

Currently, it just basically passes null to the database and gives me a success message.

If I change...

```
  $field = $_POST['db_field'];
   $value = $_POST['db_value'];
```

To...

```
  $field = 233;
  $value = 234;
```

It puts the number 234 in the proper column of item 233 in my database as I would like.  So basically whatever is in that link is not getting passed properly to the post, but I don't know how to fix it. Any help would be awesome.

Comment: your post variables are `field` and `val`... not `db_field` and `db_value`. Look at your data option in the ajax. either change field/val to db_field/db_value or change it in the php

Comment: I think that was it. I'm a complete javascript noob and I didn't write that part.  I don't know why I assumed it would be right. Changing it to db_value: $(this).attr("db_value") etc worked! Thank you!

Comment: I know it seems like answering questions for a noob like me might be a waste of time but that answer gave me all I needed to make about 6 different types of functions with that ajax code above and was soooo helpful. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your data variable to this

```
data: {
           action: 'save',
           db_field: $(this).attr("db_field"),
           db_val: $(this).attr("db_value")
         },
```

And it won't send null value

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! That's it!

Answer (score 0):

Your variable name in js is this :

```
**field**: $(this).attr("db_field"),
**val**: $(this).attr("db_value")
```

So in php file use:

```
$_POST['field'];
$_POST['val'];
```

to get values of these two variables.